# An idiom that means "to carefully choose words while speaking"

Tags: idiom-request

Is there an idiom that means "to carefully choose words while speaking"?

> Her topic was extremely sensitive, so she **carefully chose her words
> as she spoke**.

I asked the same question to a Japanese teacher of English. She said it might be better to use "to speak in measured terms". But I guessed it might sound too formal in ordinary conversation, hence my question

Comment: What's wrong with "carefully choose her words"? What problem is there with that phrase that you hope to solve with some other phrasing?

Comment: @Jay I asked the same question to a Japanese teacher of English. She said it might be better to use "to speak in measured terms". But I guessed it might sound too formal in ordinary conversation, hence my question.

Comment: "Her topic was extremely sensitive, so she **spoke very deliberately**". Also thoughtfully.

Comment: I think "carefully chose her words" is fine to use in ordinary conversation. I don't think it's too formal at all.

Comment: @Kaguyahime the "measured terms" one is basically wrong.  You wouldn't say that.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "measured terms", but it's often found in the negative form, "in no measured terms" which means to speak forcefully and without consideration for sentiment.

Comment: Aside from the other answers, I'd say 'mind your tongue' is a somewhat threatening way of saying that.

Comment: The best way to say this will vary a bit depending on the context. For example, you could say "... she spoke diplomatically", which would work very well in some contexts, but would not work in other contexts.

Comment: Your sentence contains the right words, but the word order is not idiomatic.  The correct way of arranging these words is "Her topic was extremely sensitive, so she **chose here words carefully**". "Her topic" implies that this is a prepared speech. Adding "as she spoke" states that she was deciding what to say as she was speaking, This would not be true if she was presenting a prepared speech.

Answer (score 20):

"Choose [ones] words carefully" *is* an idiom, normally parsed that way, although there's nothing wrong with the word order in your sentence as it is.

Some alternatives spring to mind but you'd likely have to adjust the word order to fit your sentence, so if you're looking for something as a recognisable idiom it may not be what you want.

- think before you speak
- mind your language
- tread carefully (metaphorical)

So you could say:

- she thought (carefully) before speaking.
- she was mindful of her language (or *words*)
- she trod carefully

Comment: Thank you very much, Astralbee. I think "tread carefully" is what I was looking for. According to the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary, "tread warily" is also possible. By the way, can I use "tread lightly" as the opposite of "tread carefully"?

Comment: @Kaguyahime 'Warily' sounds more linguistically interesting but perhaps less natural. 'Lightly' is another choice, but maybe more what you'd say about speaking to someone who is 'fragile'. It certainly isn't the *opposite* - they all mean choosing the right words so as not to upset/offend etc

Comment: An idiom has meaning not deducible from the words themselves. "Choose one's words carefully" might be  a *set phrase*, but it has no meaning beyond the normal dictionary definitions of each word taken individually - it's not an idiom.

Comment: "Mind your language" doesn't apply at all, at least in the US. It's too specific. That means to avoid using vulgar language, and especially profanity.

Comment: @Kaguyahime "Tread lightly" means the about the same as "Tread carefully." I think of a person tip-toeing through a dark area, with some kind of trap nearby. If they're not very careful about how they step, they could set off the trap, or wake up an ogre, or whatever.

Comment: ... treading _lightly_ would allow one to be quiet/safe; or, to touch (and therefore notice) a trap without triggering it. I agree that it applies here, although the metaphor I used above doesn't quite fit your scenario.

Comment: Thank you very much, jpaugh. "Take something lightly" is the opposite of "take something seriously", so I guessed "tread lightly" was the opposite of "tread carefully". Maybe, the meaning of "lightly" in "tread lightly" is different from that of "lightly" in "take something lightly".

Comment: You can tread lightly like Holly Golightly.

Comment: In my experience, "tread carefully" implies fear of repercussion: you'd tread carefully around the police or a powerful boss. To "tread lightly" implies trying not to cause a scene, drama, or hard feelings. You'd tread lightly when bringing up bad news to someone mourning a loved one. Both have you choosing your words carefully but they can imply more than that.

Answer (score 12):

I think **weighing your words** is another option that means *"to carefully think about everything you are going to say before you say it"* according to the Cambridge dictionary. I'm not a native speaker so I don't know how common this idiom is.

Comment: This *is* a common idiom, in my experience as a native speaker from SE England. It isn't even particularly formal.

Comment: The idiom that comes to mind is "think [carefully] before you speak"

Comment: I think this is the best answer without more context. Alternatively, you could say "... she spoke tactfully", which conveys the meaning succinctly and precisely, but uses an uncommon word and doesn't use an idiom.

Answer (score 2):

Coming at it a little differently, you can also say that you **don't want to put your foot in your mouth**. This means you want to avoid saying something that you might regret after you've said it.

Answer (score 1):

"**Choose your words wisely**" is what we say around here when attempting to convey that. North Central US. While wisely and carefully are different, thats what is said to tell people to speak carefully.

Answer (score 1):

The topic was a sensitive one with this particular audience so she was **walking on eggshells**. Or use **treading on eggshells** for more of a UK sound to the idiom.

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/walk_on_eggshells#:%7E:text=(idiomatic)%20To%20be%20overly%20careful,in%20handling%20very%20sensitive%20matters.):

> verb
>
> **walk on eggshells** (third-person singular simple present **walks on
> eggshells**, present participle **walking on eggshells**, simple past and
> past participle **walked on eggshells**)
>
> (idiomatic) To be overly careful in dealing with a person or situation
> because they get angry or offended very easily; to try very hard not
> to upset someone or something.
>
> (idiomatic) To be careful and
> sensitive, in handling very sensitive matters.

Answer (score 0):

A related, but not exact idiom is to ***bite one's tongue***. This implies that a person is very deliberately *refraining* from saying something that they otherwise would. It's a specific case of carefully choosing one's words, in particular being careful about what is *not* said, rather that carefully choosing the words that *are* said. Both it and "choose your words carefully" imply that there are certain things which one should avoid saying.

Answer (score 0):

One phrase that expresses the idea:

Speak guardedly

Answer (score -1):

Before editing this, I originally said that the English expression for choosing one's words carefully really is "choosing one's words carefully." And I still think this is true as far as it goes. But "tread carefully" is a good phrase too, and probably better in the example given. There is a lot of overlap, but, roughly speaking, I would say that you *tread carefully* when you are trying not to offend or otherwise damage the social dynamic, and you *choose your words carefully* when you want to be truthful without revealing certain information, or situations similar to that. (But either expression could be used in the opposite situation - I just think this may be a slight tendency.)

For some empirical evidence that both expressions are common:
[image: Google ngram plot showing "tread carefully" maybe 2.5-3 times as common as "choosing his/her/your words carefully"]

Comment: That's a very misleading use of an ngram... you've diluted the use of one saying by using three different pronouns (there could be more - *ones, theirs, my, our* etc) and compared them against a saying without context that will include *literal* uses of walking as well as the metaphorical meaning of speaking. It's certainly not "empirical evidence"!

Comment: Treat carefully fits only generally, because it isn't specific to speech. It  can be applied to any action.

Answer (score -2):

ELOQUENTLY

To speak ' eloquently ' is to speak with fluensy (ease and accuracy) and persuasiveness ( source: quora).

ARTICULATE

an ' articulate ' speaker is one thay expresses their ideas clearly and effectively thru writing or speaking. ( source: Brittanica )

EXAMPLE:

How eloquent ! - in the way she articulated her words with ease , expressing her position on the matter clearly yet respectfully .

( the example is from me not quora or Brittanica ).